# WPF - Set TextBox Text to value of dropdown menu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to set the Text of a textbox to a value of a dropdown menu of another window in wpf.

I searched online for an solution, but the problem seems to be too specific and I don't know how to formulate a proper search.

I have the following code in MainWindow.xaml:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="SelectServerDropdown" SelectedIndex="0" Margin="95,289,481.333,106.667" Padding ="2, 2, 2, 2" Height="Auto">
<ComboBoxItem>Server 1</ComboBoxItem>
<ComboBoxItem>Server 2</ComboBoxItem>
```

To get the selected item and value, in MainWindow.xaml.cs, I have:

```cs
ComboBoxItem selectServerDropdownItem = (ComboBoxItem)SelectServerDropdown.SelectedItem;
string ServerName = selectServerDropdownItem.Content.ToString();
```

I start OptionsWindow.xaml by clicking on an "options" button in MainWindow.xaml. What should I put in OptionsWindow.xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text="Servername" FontWeight="Bold"/>
<TextBox x:Name="ServernameField" Padding="2px" Text=???/>
```

Or how can I retrieve the value to pass it to "Text" in OptionsWindow.xaml?

Comment: You should use a bridging object of some sort. That could be a static class, a resource or a viewmodel. Which is best depends on details you've not explained. Also. You should not drag around controls onto or in the designer. Fixed large margins lead to problems when you deliver an app to any user has different display settings.

Comment: How about setting `optionsWindow.ServernameField.Text = ServerName;` after you have created the `OptionsWindow` in the `MainWindow` class? This would be the solution if you are not using the MVVM design pattern.

Comment: Thanks! I went with the MVVM design pattern and will also dig a bit deeper into it, because it seems really interesting, but for other people looking at this that don't want to use it, this would be the perfect fix!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's time to take a look at the [MVVM Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel).

You should have a view model class with properties that the views use as source for data bindings. Both windows would share an instance of the view model in their DataContext.

The most simple view model:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<string> ServerNames { get; }
        = new string[] { "Server 1", "Server 2" };

    public string SelectedServerName { get; set; }
        = "Server 1";
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = viewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

It would be used by the ComboBox like

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ServerNames}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedServerName}"/>
```

The OptionsWindow would use

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedServerName}"/>
```

and its DataContext would be set on creation in MainWindow:

```
var options = new OptionsWindow { DataContext = viewModel };
options.Show();
```

---

If the ComboBox in MainWindow would need to be updated when you change the view model's `SelectedServerName` property in code behind, the view model class would need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and fire the PropertyChanged event from the property setter.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was stuck and this beautifully binds together everything!

Comment: @MatthiasG. You're welcome. Be aware that there are many potential pitfalls in WPF with MVVM. I strongly recommend reading [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview) and [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Answer (score 0):

You can access the values from your main window like so:

```
((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow)
```

You just call the existing instance of MainWindow and cast it so you can access its members.

After that you just use the code behind to fill in the value from `ServerName` which you populated yourself in MainWindow:

```
ServernameField.Text = ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).ServerName;
```